# Trouble getting R to recognize Date data as Dates

Tags: r

I currently am very new with R and am working with stock data. I am trying to set up a date and closing price dataset with 3 different stocks. I have merged all 3 stocks by date into one dataset, but now I have no clue how to get R to recognize my column "Date" as actual dates, instead of numerals. I need to plot date by price for these stocks. I have dabbled with as.Date() but I think that the necessary format for this command is 01/01/15, whereas the format I have for my data is in 1/1/15. Long story short, I cannot change the format in Excel then import it back over, so I am currently stuck with 1/1/15 format and unable to get R to recognize my data as dates. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sorry for wall of text.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is enough material on this site to solve your issue. Please search first and come back if you cannot find any suitable answer, with some sample data and code.

Comment: Read `?striptime`. Default format is not as you imagine it. There must be hundreds of worked examples in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the format it expects (assuming that's 1 January 2015?) is "2015-01-01" or similar. You can use base R's tools but they're more painful for you as a user than say, lubridate - a package designed just for date formatting that includes something for handling day-month-year dates:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
day <- "1/1/15"
as.Date(dmy(day))
[1] "2015-01-01"
```

Give that a whirl, see if it works for you.